# Using LOAD DATA in mysql to import to a table with a single field separated by semicolons

Tags: mysql, import

I have a good example of the load data statement in mysql, but it assumes you have more than just the id field and one data field in your table and in your file. My file is of literature citations where I'm importing the whole citation as a single text field and I want it to auto-increment the id, and I'm going to do keyword searches on the whole citation.

How do I modify the load data statement to leave out fields terminated by--because there's a single field per record, and the records are terminated by a semicolon.

The data is lousy with punctuation. Commas, periods, single quotes (the original data has double quotes. To avoid escaping the double quotes I'm replacing them with single quotes). But it doesn't have any semicolons in it, which is why semicolons are separating the rows.

I haven't tried it yet, I'm trying to understand how to structure the load data command.

I tried this and got a 1064 syntax error:

load data local infile
'C:/Users/owner/OneDrive/Documents/Capstone/References_flat_file.txt'

into table cites

lines terminated by ';'

('cite');

Here are the first few lines of the file:

Agrawal, R. et al. (1993). ‘Mining Association Rules between Sets of Items in Large Databases,’ Proceedings of the 1993 ACM SIGMOD Conference, Washington, DC, 207’216.;Alexander, C. (1964). Notes on the Synthesis of Form. Cambridge, MA: Harvard University Press.;Arazy, O., Kumar, N., and Shapira, B. (2010). ‘A Theory-Driven Design Framework for Social Recommender Systems.’ Journal of the Association for Information Systems 11(9): 455’490.;

The lines are terminated by semicolons. There is only one field per line so the fields are terminated by nothing. I looked at the manual and thought the fields section was optional. My table has two fields, cite_id, which is auto-incremented, and cite. The fields aren't terminated by anything because there is only one.

Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: I found my syntax error. I got rid of ('cites'). Now I get a different error:

Error 3948 that load data must be enabled from both the client and server sides. How do I do this?

Got a little farther. Now the error I get is this:

ERROR 2068 request rejected due to restrictions on access.

I added local_infile=ON to the my.ini file in both the client and server sections, running Notepad as administrator, and saved it.

I stopped and restarted the server.
I exited and restarted Workbench.

I still get the error.

UPDATE: There is an unfixed bug in Workbench 8.0 where it will not allow the load data command no matter what you do. The command has to be run from the command line client.

Now when I use the following command I get ids for the records populated but my cite field is blank.

load data local infile 'C:/Users/owner/OneDrive/Documents/Capstone/References_flat_file.txt'
into table cites
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '/n';

When I put ('cite') on the next line I get a syntax error.

Comment: Rather than attempt to describe the data, post a few rows here, and add the schema that you're importing it into.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

load data local infile 'C:/Users/owner/OneDrive/Documents/Capstone/References_flat_file.txt'

into table cites

lines terminated by ';'

(cite);

This command had to be run from the SQL command line client because Workbench for MySQL 8.0 has a long-unfixed bug where it will not perform the load data command no matter what you do.

To get the permissions I had to put

local_infile=ON
loose-local-infile = 1

into the client section of C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini

and had to put
local_infile=ON into the server section of the same file.